# c# Как перейти в другой класс

Tags: c#

Заранее прошу прощения за тупой вопрос. Но допустим я работаю в одном классе, есть определенный цикл, в котором условием является переход в другой класс. Как это реализовать? То есть if (e == e1) то идет запуск того, что на написано допустим в class program2

Comment: что есть "переход в другой класс"?

Comment: Давайте для начала без классов. Вообще. Любую задачу, которую можно решить с классами, можно решить и без них. Опишите вашу задачу, забудьте на время про классы.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (e == e1)
  program2.SomeStaticMethod();
```

Comment: SomeStaticMethod подчеркивается красным

Comment: Как Вы относитесь к мысли почитать какую-нибудь книжку про C#? После этого, возможно,  не придется начинать с "прошу прощения за тупой вопрос".

Comment: я начинающий) может быть Вы расскажете в чем дело?

Comment: Нет, не расскажу. См. комментарий выше.

Comment: Сколько желчи и нарциссизма)

Comment: @kardlnal: Понимаете, для того, чтобы объяснить начала программирования, нужен текст объема небольшой книжки. Причём это умным и талантливым авторам книжек легко в такой сжатой форме всё объяснить, а обыкновенным нам придётся потратить куда больше текста.

Comment: Нда. Я бы тоже не взялся. Красным подчёркивается наверное потому что вы ещё описали этот метод и его просто нет нигде в коде -- об этом и говорит вам подчёркивание. Ошибка, мол. Я вполне понимаю коллег, что вытаскивать вас из болота незнания -- достаточно сложное дело и в общем-то совет про чтение книжек весьма справедлив. Ну и чтобы было более желчно: желчь, желчь, желчь.